# SQL Timestamp overflows in Android Java

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've been writing an Android app and ran into a strange problem.  I have a database set up with the internal Android SQL database, and have a field defined as a timestamp.  Problem is retrieving the value seems like it can't be done without causing an overflow to the long datatype, and as far as I can tell there's no biginteger fetch from the SQL database or anything else helpful.

Is there something I'm missing about retrieving the timestamp value from the SQL database?

edit: apparently the value may be overflowing internally to the SQLite database due to the lack of an actual TIMESTAMP type.

Comment: Sqlite doesn't have a 'timestamp' type. How are you storing the time in the database?

Comment: The android version does.  The field is defined as type TIMESTAMP:

mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HealthyUnhealthy(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, activity VARCHAR NOT NULL, category VARCHAR, time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, unhealthy INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);");

Comment: You can use almost anything you want as a column type in sqlite. fhtrdsdvhu is valid. See https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html for details.

Comment: Interesting.  Though it doesn't change the problem.  There's no way to retrieve the timestamp since getLong isn't sufficient and overflows.  Unless of course it's overflowing internally due to some other problem with how it's defined.

Comment: It appears that the database is actually overflowing internally.  I tried changing the type to INT, REAL and even BLOB and all of them overflow.  BLOB overflowing makes no real sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is not with SQLite but with your handling of the extracted data.

It could stem from your use of `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and not realising that this will save the data as a String (column type TEXT in SQLite) in the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` not as a long and then trying to convert this to a long from a string **(see `at a.a.so67813806javatimestampoverflow.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43))` in the results of the demo.**

As such the fix could be two fold:-

1. store data in the same format (or handle it appropriately when extracting it, the former being the more ideal solution)
2. use the appropriate get???? method when retrieving the data from the Cursor. i.e. to get a long use getLong etc

As far as overflowing, there is plenty of latitude. For example take Java's `System.currentTimeMillis()` this will return the date and time down to 1000's of seconds.

- At the date/time 2021-06-03 12:33:35.579 such a value would be 1622687615571.

Multiplying this by 100000 results in 1,622,687,615,574,000,000 which can still be stored and retrieved as a long (still within the 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 limit of a long).

**Demo**

As proof of the ability consider the following demo/app based upon your snippet show the SQL used to create your table.

First the Database Helper **DBHelper** :-

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HealthyUnhealthy(" +
                "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " +
                "activity VARCHAR NOT NULL, " +
                "category VARCHAR, " +
                "time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " +
                "unhealthy INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long insert(String activity, String category, Long timeStamp, boolean unhealthy) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("activity",activity);
        cv.put("category",category);
        if (timeStamp != null) {
            cv.put("time", timeStamp);
        }
        cv.put("unhealthy",unhealthy);
        return db.insert("HealthyUnhealthy",null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAllData() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{
                "id","activity","category","time","unhealthy","typeOf(time)"
        };
        return db.query("HealthyUnhealthy",columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

- of most concern are the **insert** and **getAllData** methods
- **insert** caters for insert via the default (if the Long passed is null) or any long passed.
- **getAlldata** returns a Cursor with all columns plus an additional column that shows the storage type of the time (note this is the type used to store the data NOT the type affinity aka the column type used to define the column)

Second is an activity, **MainActivity** that uses the database and the previously described methods.

- Some rows are inserted, the first using Java's `System.currentTimeInMillis()`, the 2nd using the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and the other 6 the system time multiplied by a factor of 10.
- All the data is extracted into a Cursor.
- The Cursor is dumped
- The Cursor is traversed and the columns extracted. The time column is extracted numerous times using various Cursor get???? methods.

:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = new DBHelper(this);
        db.insert("Activity1","Category1",System.currentTimeMillis(),false);
        db.insert("Activity2","Category2",null,false); // use default
        db.insert("Activity3","Category3",System.currentTimeMillis() * 10,false);
        db.insert("Activity4","Category4",System.currentTimeMillis() * 100,false);
        db.insert("Activity5","Category5",System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000,false);
        db.insert("Activity6","Category6",System.currentTimeMillis() * 10000,false);
        db.insert("Activity7","Category7",System.currentTimeMillis() * 100000,false);
        db.insert("Activity8","Category8",System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000000,false);


        Cursor csr = db.getAllData();
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            long time =csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("time"));
            Log.d(
                    "TIMEINFO",
                    "Time for Activity " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("activity")) +
                            " is (as long) " + csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("time")) +
                            " as (float) " + csr.getFloat(csr.getColumnIndex("time")) +
                            " as (Double) " + csr.getDouble(csr.getColumnIndex("time")) +
                            " as (String) " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("time")) +
                            " as (Int) " + csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex("time"))
            );
            try {
                long x = Long.parseLong(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("time")));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

**Results**

First the Cursor as dumped :-

```
2021-06-03 13:25:42.748 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@6131588
2021-06-03 13:25:42.749 I/System.out: 0 {
2021-06-03 13:25:42.749 I/System.out:    ID=1
2021-06-03 13:25:42.749 I/System.out:    activity=Activity1
2021-06-03 13:25:42.749 I/System.out:    category=Category1
2021-06-03 13:25:42.749 I/System.out:    time=1622690742744
2021-06-03 13:25:42.749 I/System.out:    unhealthy=0
2021-06-03 13:25:42.749 I/System.out:    typeOf(time)=integer
2021-06-03 13:25:42.749 I/System.out: }
2021-06-03 13:25:42.749 I/System.out: 1 {
2021-06-03 13:25:42.749 I/System.out:    ID=2
2021-06-03 13:25:42.750 I/System.out:    activity=Activity2
2021-06-03 13:25:42.750 I/System.out:    category=Category2
2021-06-03 13:25:42.750 I/System.out:    time=2021-06-03 03:25:42
2021-06-03 13:25:42.750 I/System.out:    unhealthy=0
2021-06-03 13:25:42.750 I/System.out:    typeOf(time)=text
2021-06-03 13:25:42.750 I/System.out: }
2021-06-03 13:25:42.750 I/System.out: 2 {
2021-06-03 13:25:42.750 I/System.out:    ID=3
2021-06-03 13:25:42.750 I/System.out:    activity=Activity3
2021-06-03 13:25:42.750 I/System.out:    category=Category3
2021-06-03 13:25:42.750 I/System.out:    time=16226907427450
2021-06-03 13:25:42.750 I/System.out:    unhealthy=0
2021-06-03 13:25:42.750 I/System.out:    typeOf(time)=integer
2021-06-03 13:25:42.750 I/System.out: }
2021-06-03 13:25:42.750 I/System.out: 3 {
2021-06-03 13:25:42.750 I/System.out:    ID=4
2021-06-03 13:25:42.750 I/System.out:    activity=Activity4
2021-06-03 13:25:42.750 I/System.out:    category=Category4
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out:    time=162269074274600
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out:    unhealthy=0
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out:    typeOf(time)=integer
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out: }
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out: 4 {
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out:    ID=5
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out:    activity=Activity5
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out:    category=Category5
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out:    time=1622690742746000
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out:    unhealthy=0
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out:    typeOf(time)=integer
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out: }
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out: 5 {
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out:    ID=6
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out:    activity=Activity6
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out:    category=Category6
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out:    time=16226907427470000
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out:    unhealthy=0
2021-06-03 13:25:42.751 I/System.out:    typeOf(time)=integer
2021-06-03 13:25:42.752 I/System.out: }
2021-06-03 13:25:42.752 I/System.out: 6 {
2021-06-03 13:25:42.752 I/System.out:    ID=7
2021-06-03 13:25:42.752 I/System.out:    activity=Activity7
2021-06-03 13:25:42.752 I/System.out:    category=Category7
2021-06-03 13:25:42.752 I/System.out:    time=162269074274700000
2021-06-03 13:25:42.752 I/System.out:    unhealthy=0
2021-06-03 13:25:42.752 I/System.out:    typeOf(time)=integer
2021-06-03 13:25:42.752 I/System.out: }
2021-06-03 13:25:42.752 I/System.out: 7 {
2021-06-03 13:25:42.752 I/System.out:    ID=8
2021-06-03 13:25:42.752 I/System.out:    activity=Activity8
2021-06-03 13:25:42.752 I/System.out:    category=Category8
2021-06-03 13:25:42.753 I/System.out:    time=1622690742748000000
2021-06-03 13:25:42.753 I/System.out:    unhealthy=0
2021-06-03 13:25:42.753 I/System.out:    typeOf(time)=integer
2021-06-03 13:25:42.753 I/System.out: }
2021-06-03 13:25:42.753 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

- **NOTE** The second row (Activity2) has a storage type of **TEXT** as per I/System.out:    `typeOf(time)=text` and the data is stored as as `time=2021-06-03 02:45:36`. All other rows the type is **INTEGER**.

The second part of output is from the traversal of the Cursor and is :-

```
2021-06-03 13:25:42.753 D/TIMEINFO: Time for Activity Activity1 is (as long) 1622690742744 as (float) 1.62269076E12 as (Double) 1.622690742744E12 as (String) 1622690742744 as (Int) -806895144
2021-06-03 13:25:42.753 D/TIMEINFO: Time for Activity Activity2 is (as long) 2021 as (float) 2021.0 as (Double) 2021.0 as (String) 2021-06-03 03:25:42 as (Int) 2021
2021-06-03 13:25:42.753 W/System.err: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2021-06-03 03:25:42"
2021-06-03 13:25:42.754 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:594)
2021-06-03 13:25:42.754 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:636)
2021-06-03 13:25:42.754 W/System.err:     at a.a.so67813806javatimestampoverflow.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
2021-06-03 13:25:42.754 W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
2021-06-03 13:25:42.754 W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
2021-06-03 13:25:42.754 W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
2021-06-03 13:25:42.754 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
2021-06-03 13:25:42.755 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
2021-06-03 13:25:42.755 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
2021-06-03 13:25:42.755 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
2021-06-03 13:25:42.755 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
2021-06-03 13:25:42.755 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
2021-06-03 13:25:42.755 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2021-06-03 13:25:42.755 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
2021-06-03 13:25:42.755 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
2021-06-03 13:25:42.756 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-06-03 13:25:42.756 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
2021-06-03 13:25:42.756 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2021-06-03 13:25:42.756 D/TIMEINFO: Time for Activity Activity3 is (as long) 16226907427450 as (float) 1.62269076E13 as (Double) 1.622690742745E13 as (String) 16226907427450 as (Int) 520983162
2021-06-03 13:25:42.757 D/TIMEINFO: Time for Activity Activity4 is (as long) 162269074274600 as (float) 1.62269082E14 as (Double) 1.622690742746E14 as (String) 162269074274600 as (Int) 914864424
2021-06-03 13:25:42.757 D/TIMEINFO: Time for Activity Activity5 is (as long) 1622690742746000 as (float) 1.62269072E15 as (Double) 1.622690742746E15 as (String) 1622690742746000 as (Int) 558709648
2021-06-03 13:25:42.757 D/TIMEINFO: Time for Activity Activity6 is (as long) 16226907427470000 as (float) 1.62269072E16 as (Double) 1.622690742747E16 as (String) 16226907427470000 as (Int) 1292139184
2021-06-03 13:25:42.757 D/TIMEINFO: Time for Activity Activity7 is (as long) 162269074274700000 as (float) 1.6226907E17 as (Double) 1.622690742747E17 as (String) 162269074274700000 as (Int) 36489952
2021-06-03 13:25:42.758 D/TIMEINFO: Time for Activity Activity8 is (as long) 1622690742748000000 as (float) 1.62269073E18 as (Double) 1.622690742748E18 as (String) 1622690742748000000 as (Int) 365899520
```

- As can be seen 1622688336337000000 has been stored and retrieved without issue this much larger than any timestamp that is accurate down to milli-seconds and well handled by the Cursor methods `getLong()`, `getString()`, `getFloat()` and `getDouble()`
- **HOWEVER**, again there are issues with the 2nd row. All but the `getString()` method only gets 2021 (first non numeric and that's it, so the method do a reasonable job of returning something).
- **MOST IMPORTANT/RELEVANT** is that the attempt to parse the 2nd row into a long results in `at a.a.so67813806javatimestamp**overflow**.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)`